# Windows Ffmpeg - send audio to sound card's output

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, output, soundcard

I have a sound card (Behringer UMC202HD) which connected to a Windows 10 computer by usb cable, i am able to recieve audio from input device with the following ffmpeg command:
`ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="IN 1-2 (BEHRINGER UMC 202HD 192k)" -map_channel 0.0.0 -c:a pcm_s24le first_channel.wav -map_channel 0.0.1 -c:a pcm_s24le second_channel.wav`

But i can't send audio to sound card's output with the ffmpeg, is there any way to do this? if there is, how can i do it?

Linux version (pseudo command) of what i'm trying to do in Windows:

`ffmpeg -i my_input.wav -f alsa alsa.behringer_out`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it with the ffmpeg.exe but, i found a simple way of it with the ffplay:

- Set the system's output to sound card from Windows sound settings and turn on mono audio option, simply run this code for send the output audio card's channel 1:
- `ffplay -i input.mp4 -af pan="stereo|c1=c1" -nodisp`
- for the channel 0 and channel 1:
- `ffplay -i input.mp4 -af pan="stereo|c0=c0|c1=c1" -nodisp`

Comment: Is it possible to select specific device?

Comment: @skhalymon Sorry for the late response, in this solution, switching the specific sound device output on Windows sound settings, and leaving the desired device selected for as long as the ffplay code is running would work.

Comment: thanks! I'm need to run few instance of ffplay\ffmpeg and stream audio into different devices outputs. Seems it's not possible with this solution.